# Statistical columnwise comparisons in pandas / Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics, comparison

I have a huge data frame DF, like this, with some 200 rows and 200 columns:

```
UIN GROUP v1  v2   v3   cat1   cat2   cat3 ...
1   A     2.0 3.0  5.0  1      0      0    
2   B     1.0 4.0  6.0  0      1      1
3   A     3.0 5.0  7.0  1      0      0
```

I want to perform statistical comparisons and linear/logistic regressions for every columns. In R I can simply do this:

```
lapply(DF[c(2:5)], function(x) wilcox.test(x ~ GROUP, data = DF, exact = FALSE))
# or multiple groups:
lapply(DF[c(2:5)], function(x) kruskal.test(x ~ GROUP, data = DF))
```

and

```
lapply(DF[c(2,6,7,8)], function(x) fisher.test(x ~ DF$GROUP))
```

and

```
lapply(DF[c(2:8), function(x) glm(GROUP ~ x, data = DF, family = "binomial")
```

It's very quick and handy and we can see the full results in a list.

**Is there any way to get such elegant output in python?** 
I need to perform columnwise group splitting and performing basic tests: ttest, wilcox test, chisq, fisher and some regressions. I don't like decisions using R packages import to Python.

Comment: See if this helps you https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wilcoxon.html

Comment: Thank you!
But the question is in elegant columnwise comparison in panadas df, not in the statistical test)